# What is the meaning of Division (Average Gain / Average Loss) in the RSI indicator?

Tags: divisibility

The formula of RSI indicator (RSI = 100 - (100 / (1 + RS), RS = Average Gain / Average Loss), given the definition of division is to split an amount into equally-sized group.

Here, based on the definition of division, does it mean we are splitting Average Gain into equally-sized Average Loss group? I couldn't form a picture in my mind when I think of this. Or the definition of division actually implies another interpretation?